# Why doesn't this threaded network code work? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, client-server

Code for server:

http://stikked.com/view/64826511

Network Code for client:

http://stikked.com/view/38974838

Basically, the client connects to the server, but beyond that, it does not work. When a message is sent, the client's System.out.println indicates that the GUI is calling the correct function. But there is no sign of the server ever recieving the in put. If I telnet into the server, it functions correctly.

This is my first unaided attempt at both threaded code, and java networking. Up till now, most of my programming has been web apps or very simple desktop apps (e.g. Calculator).

(If your answer is "Your doing it all wrong", please point to a correct tutorial for a client-server program where both the client and server can send messages at any time. All the tutorials I've seen have the client execute a few hardcoded commands, then quit)

Comment: The person that downvoted, and voted to close, could you please explain why? (I'm assuming it's the same person)

Comment: How is this spam? He's using a pastebin instead of putting the code here on SO, that's all. However, the code *should* be posted here so it doesn't "expire" like it would on a pastebin.

Comment: AFAIK, the pastebin I used doesn't expire. My main reason for using the pastebin, was the minimum amount of code I could think to be relevant, is still significantly longer than the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two immediate problems - you're using a `PrintWriter`, which means it won't throw any exceptions if it can't actually talk to the server. You're also not calling `flush()`, so it may well just be buffering the data.

I would suggest:

- Use `OutputStreamWriter` instead of `PrintWriter`, and handle exceptions appropriately. This will remove buffering as well. You *may* want to wrap it in a `BufferedWriter` and then call `flush()` after you're "done" with a message.
- Specify the appropriate charset, e.g. UTF-8.

Comment: Changing to OutputStreamWriter and calling flush() fixed it. How do I specify a charset?

Comment: Use the overload for the OutputStreamWriter constructor which takes a charset name, e.g. "utf8".